# How to return a boolean value that lets you know wether or not two circles overlap

Tags: java

I am currently working on a project for my java class where I have to make a method to take in a circle that is being called an "Animal" as an argument.

With this argument I then have to return a `boolean` value indicating whether or not the two "Animals" overlap. Note: To know if the circles are overlapping, there centers must be less than one radius apart. I'm not really sure how to start this and whether or not I should be using an if statement or not. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should at least attempt to provide some code. However, you have some point of circle1 (x,y), with a radius. And circle2 (x2,y2), with a radius. It is just math to determine **if** (good hint, there) the circles overlap. I'm assuming a 2D plane.

Comment: Honestly, don't even think about the Java code to accomplish this task until you understand the *math* to accomplish this task.  Find out how to calculate the distance between two points.  Once you understand how to do that, the Java code is pretty trivial.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind the math and geometrical figures is very interesting, you can find more things to learn [here][http://mathworld.wolfram.com/]:

In your case, 2 circles, no matter is they have different radius, they intersect if and only if **the distance between their centers is smaller than sum of their radius**

take a look at the illustration if you need a graphical reference..

[image]

## Code:

you need the center of the circle and the radius, with just that you can geometrically create a circle, then:

1. create a method that returns the distance between 2 points
   and call it by passing as parameter both centers of the circles,
2. the rest is subtraction and there is the logic that return the boolean you need.